# Prevent my Win32 application's UI elements from being scaled up when high DPI is set

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-studio-2008, dpi

When windows is set to "resize text to "125%", my Win32 application has its UI (but not its window size) scaled up. This causes text strings to be cut off and UI elements to disappear off the edge of the window.

I would like to prevent this from happening, so that text isn't scaled up, and the app displays correctly. As the time investment to get this old legacy app properly DPI-aware is too high, and I just want to make the app usable by preventing Windows from breaking the UI by resizing UI elements.

I have tried calling SetProcessDPIAware() during startup, and when that didn't work, signalling that the app is DPI Aware in its manifest. However, neither of these measures has any effect.

The manifest fragment I am using to specify DPI awareness:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' standalone='yes'?>
<assembly xmlns='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1' manifestVersion='1.0'>
  <asmv3:application
           xmlns:asmv3="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <asmv3:windowsSettings
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2005/WindowsSettings">
      <dpiAware>true</dpiAware>
    </asmv3:windowsSettings>
  </asmv3:application>
</assembly>
```

Comment: "manifest" and "assembly" don't sound like standard C++. Are you using C++/CLI or C#? You should properly retag your question.

Comment: @ArneMertz, unfortunately Microsoft made manifests necessary for regular C++ too. It's the way to get UAC elevation for example.

Comment: @ArneMertz The assembly manifest is standard Win32 and has been is use since Windows XP when it allowed theming (among other things), then Vista/7 where it specified the required permissions and elevation.

Comment: mackenir, is this a view or a dialog?

Comment: Are you forcing any particular window size anywhere? That would most likley DPI UNaware, causing the cut off text when Windows tries to adjust accordingly.

Comment: @Deanna, although window size is one issue (not sure where it's coming from), text is also truncated (losing eg the last word of the sentence) because the size of the text control isn't scaled up enough to fit all its text using the larger font.

Comment: @Deanna so, I have one text control "blah blah blah blah" and aligned at the end of this 'sentence' I have another chunk of text that I progrmmatically convert to a clickable link. The end result is a sentence of text with the last word 'linkified'. However when scaled up, the last word 'blah' is lost, and the link text is awkwardly moved so that there's a big gap between it and the rest of the text. So window size is not the only problem.

Comment: @MarkRansom I'm using WTL, so the app is a CFrameWindowImpl, containing a CTabView, inside of which there are three tabs. One of them is a CDialogImpl, defined in a dialog resource. This dialog is where scaling makes a mess.

Comment: OK, I found where window size is set and did some arithmetic with DPI to scale that. The other problem I can probably get round by just... getting rid of that link. I've already wasted too much time on this horrible old archaic app. Ugh.

Comment: @MarkRansom thanks for clarifying that to me, didn't know that. Up to now my Windows "apps" were plain console applications and frameworks that had no need (or use) for such things.

Comment: @mackenir The label positioning will need to be calculated, not just placed. Your current scheme will break equally on systems with different standard fonts, or opentype, etc. Either use a link aware control, or calculate the size of each bit of text and position the next to suit.

Comment: @Deanna "label positioning will need to be calculated". Indeed - and given the effort required to achieve simple stuff like this in WTL I wont be bothering :). It's a shame there's no way to just say "Windows, please don't break my UI by ineptly trying to scale it up"...

Comment: It's not inept, it's doing all it can, you need to do your part and [pay your taxes](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/08/22/454487.aspx). What would you do with a partially sighted users that needs large fonts to be able to see the screen?

Comment: "What would you do with a partially sighted users that needs large fonts"

Recommend they set font size to 150% so that windows scales up the non-broken UI ;)

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problems with SDL OpenGL.  Windows DPI scaling on unaware applications is very poorly implemented, such as zooming in a fullscreen viewport and cropping off the sides.

I didn't have any luck with the manifest.

I was able to solve it by calling `SetProcessDPIAware();` but it had to happen before SDLmain executed.  Maybe your "during startup" wasn't early enough.  I use it as a global variable initializer before the `main` function:

```
BOOL dpi_result = SetProcessDPIAware();

int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
    //...
```

Answer (score 0):

For a 125% font scaling, the DPI aware setting is not relevant. What happens is that the text will be 25% bigger, and the onus is then on you to scale up your UI to match. Your dialogs will typically need to be 25% larger to accommodate the larger text. Not only do you have to scale the sizes, you also need to scale the positions. It's up to you to code all of that. Or use a UI framework that does it for you.

For font scaling larger than 125%, the DPI aware setting comes into play. What happens is:

1. If your app is not marked DPI aware, Windows will scale your app using raster image resizing. This will lead to your visual elements being pixellated.
2. If your app is marked DPI aware, Windows will render your app faithfully. Again, the onus is on you to scale your UI to fit the text.

This [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd464660.aspx) has all the gory details.

Back to your specific question. You said:

> I would like to prevent this from happening, so that text isn't scaled up, and the app displays correctly.

In other words you are saying that you would like to ignore the user's font scaling setting and render at 100% DPI irrespective of their wishes. You can do this by reducing the size of all your text by 25%. I really do not recommend that you do so.

Comment: Aren't dialogs generally sized in Dialog Units, which are based on the font size already?

Comment: Good point @Mark - this should go in the answer to make it more correct.

Comment: @David rolled back my revision, if you want to see it it's in the history.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a word of warning on wrongly suspecting MFC / Windows 7 on this issue.

I had what appeared to be the same problem. Our (older) MFC application, when ran on windows 7 with it's font set to 125%, displayed dialog boxes at the wrong size. The controls were scaled but each dialog was about 25% too small.

At first I searched through the dialog code for anything that might set its size/position. Then I saw that many people online were having trouble with dialog sizes when moving MFC applications to Windows 7, which falsely increased my suspicion of MFC / Windows 7.

Finally I read a similar discussion and found a comment by the maintainer of spy++ that a feature where it saves size/position on exit forced the window into the wrong size after a font / DPI change.  Our software was doing the same, but the code was in the main application and not in the dialogs.

Answer (score 0):

On my team's app, we have the xmlns attribute for asmv3 on the assembly attributes instead of on the application attribute.

Instead of this line:

```
<assembly xmlns='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1' manifestVersion='1.0'>
```

This line:

```
<assembly xmlns='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1' manifestVersion='1.0' xmlns:asmv3="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
```

I took my product's app manifest and stripped it down to just the  and parent nodes.  Here it is for reference:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns:asmv3="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
  <asmv3:application>
    <asmv3:windowsSettings xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2005/WindowsSettings">
      <dpiAware>true</dpiAware>
    </asmv3:windowsSettings>
  </asmv3:application>
</assembly>
```